# Xauth: timeout in lock authority file /home/user /.Xauthority

Tags: linux, xauth

I ask for your help since I am on linux and when I wanted to log in normally (typing my password) it kept loading indefinitely, and when I open the "console" with the key combination
**(ctrl alt fn f3)** and start session From there everything is fine, but when I want to start with **startx** it gives me the following error:

`Xauth: timeout in lock authority file / home / user /. Xauthority`

Try to solve it with the first two answers of ([Why am I getting this message from xauth: "timeout in locking authority file /home/<user>/.Xauthority"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215558/why-am-i-getting-this-message-from-xauth-timeoutin-locking) -authority -file-home) but it keeps giving me that error, also check the **/home/user/** folder and seeing the files with the command **ls -l .Xauthority** didn't show me anything, it gave me the error Didn't find the file, and even typing the **rm --rf Xathority** command didn't give me an error, no matter how many times I ran that command, when I rebooted my computer it still didn't work like it hadn't done anything. What I can do? Thanks in advance :) and I hope I have made myself understood.

### Update

Try to solve it also based on [this question](https://cyberwarzone.com/how-to-fix-timeout-in-locking-authority-file-home-xauthority-2018/) but it also didn't work giving me the same errors from the beginning.

I want to add that I already tried to do this:

`rm -fr .Xauth- *`

And also this:

`rm -fr / home / user / .Xauthority`

And neither way gives me an error, so I think if they are removed, but if immediately after typing those commands, I type `startx`, it keeps giving me the error of:

```
Xauth: timeout in lock authority file / home / user /. Xauthority
```

### Second update

When I try to end the ssh session it gives me errors that are the same as some people describe in this question (https://qastack.mx/ubuntu/103889/how-do-i-restart-the-ssh-service), try to fix it with the same answers from that question but it still doesn't work where there are errors at the end of the session.

Comment: Quit using `rm -rf`.  1) it's dangerous and 2) -f tells it to NOT give you any errors.  You probably need those errors.

Comment: if `ls -l .Xauthority` says file not found, can you try creating it?  `touch .Xauthority ; rm .Xauthority` .   Possibly you can't write new files?

Comment: Sorry I'm very new in Linux, let me try it without `-f` and just `-r` and the other option

Comment: the `-r` isn't necessary either.  You really shoudln't copy paste things from websites without fully understanding what they do.  Especially with the `rm` command.

Comment: @user10489 so, what sould I do then?

Comment: And I tried what you said, create the file, and I get the message `"touch: cannot touch .Xauthority : permisson denied`

Comment: The permissions on your home directory are probably wrong.

Comment: How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .Xauthority lock timeout error typically is caused by problems writing to the file.  Typical causes for this would include:

- incorrect permissions on the .Xauthority file (ownership or permissions)
- over disk quota or disk full
- incorrect permissions on the home directory

From discussion in comments, it sounds like your problem is the last of these.

Just to be sure this is the problem, run `ls -ld ~` to check the permissions on your home directory.  Likely, either you don't have write access, or you don't own the directory.  `chmod u+w ~` would fix the former, `chown $USER ~` would fix the later.

Comment: Hello, I tried what you said and it worked, the problem is that I get other errors, but I will do those better in another question

Comment: If your home directory has permissions issues, likely other files may also have the same issue.  Things like this sometimes occur from sloppy and inappropriate use of sudo.

Comment: I think that is my problem, because when I gave permissions to certain files they stopped showing errors but my computer does not work at all well, how can I return everything to how it was, how can I have all the permissions so that my computer is back well

Comment: i can't guess what you fixed on .Xauthority or what's wrong with the rest of your files without more information.

Comment: What information do you need? I can gladly give you all the information you need.

Comment: Output from `ls -l` on broken files would probably help.